# Features2d + Homography Java Implementation

Tags: android, opencv, homography

I am creating an application on Android using OpenCV and I need the Java code of the Features2d and Homography. I need it to be continuous processing like a video. I am not an expert in C++ so I couldn't port it. So if you could please provide me with the code and I'd appreciate it if it's optimized for Android.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/android-application-programming-opencv), the fourth chapter just does what you want. The publishers provide the code for free, you can download it from the link provided.